# Using externally described data structures in RPG ILE Free

Tags: rpgle

I'm having a world of issues using externally described data structures in RPG ILE Free.
The simplest issue seems to be just declaring the structure.

```
DCL-DS PALWGHT extname(SCN102DS);
  PW DIM(20) OVERLAY(PALWGHT:1); 
END-DS;
```

When I compile, it says the external file does not exist...but it does and it is in my library list.

```
 A          R PALWGHT
 A            P01WGHT       11S 3
 A            P02WGHT       11S 3
 A            P03WGHT       11S 3
 A            P04WGHT       11S 3
 A            P05WGHT       11S 3
 A            P06WGHT       11S 3
 A            P07WGHT       11S 3
 A            P08WGHT       11S 3
 A            P09WGHT       11S 3
 A            P10WGHT       11S 3
 A            P11WGHT       11S 3
 A            P12WGHT       11S 3
 A            P13WGHT       11S 3
 A            P14WGHT       11S 3
 A            P15WGHT       11S 3
 A            P16WGHT       11S 3
 A            P17WGHT       11S 3
 A            P18WGHT       11S 3
 A            P19WGHT       11S 3
 A            P20WGHT       11S 3
```

This worked prior to changing it to free format.....

```
 DPALWGHT        E DS                  EXTNAME(SCN102DS)
 DPW                             11s 3 DIM(20) OVERLAY(PALWGHT:1)
```

I'm lost.  It's probably something really stupid....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple issues. First, in free-form the file name in `EXTNAME(filename)` must be either a **Named Constant** or character literals. This is different from the fixed form variant which can be a **File Name** or character literals. If you read all the error messages you get `RNF0202 - THE PARAMETER FOR EXTNAME OR EXTFLD MUST BE A DEFINED NAMED CONSTANT OR LITERAL.` If you use a file name, it must be enclosed in quotes in free-form.

```
DCL-DS PALWGHT extname('SCN102DS');
```

`PW` is still undefined though because it does not have a type declaration. And, in free-form, `OVERLAY()` cannot point at the data structure. Instead you use `POS()`. So the whole thing should look something like:

```
DCL-DS PALWGHT extname('SCN102DS');
  PW LIKE(P01WGHT) DIM(20) POS(1); 
END-DS;
```